# Kraus Operators - unitary operation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I just want to know if a map, given by $\phi(A)=\sum_i\Omega_iA\Omega_i^{\dagger}$ with $\Omega_i=\Omega_i^{\dagger}$ for each $i$ is
unitary, or if it is possible to be something else.

I calculated something and it's crucial to know if i just reduced it to the unitary case or if i got something more interesting.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible for Kraus operators to be unitary, but this requires that you only have one of them: since they need to obey the condition
$$
\sum_i \Omega_i^\dagger \Omega_i =1,
$$
and $\Omega_i^\dagger \Omega_i\geq 0$ for each $i$, having one of them satisfy $\Omega_i^\dagger \Omega_i=1$ then forces the rest to be zero. (Similarly, if there is a single Kraus operator, then it must obviously be unitary.) The map is unitary if and only if the (single) $\Omega_i$ is (unless you've got some trivial split like e.g. $\Omega_i=\frac1NU$ independently of $i$).

It is also possible for Kraus operators to be non-unitary, and there's plenty of examples around of that kind of behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! So it is even impossible to have $\Omega_i=\Omega_i^{\dagger}$ and to have the map to be unitary, because if it was, there would only be one Kraus operator, and to be unitary it should hold that $\Omega^{\dagger}=\Omega^{-1} $ which is only possible in accordance with $\Omega=\Omega^{\dagger}$ if $\Omega=\mathbb{1}$. Is this correct? So a map described  with Kraus-operators that all are hermitian can never be unitary, exept for the unitary transformation given be the identity?

Comment: @Martin No, that's not right - there are plenty of hermitian involutions, just reflect on any hyperplane you like.

Comment: Alright -Thank You! Then ill have to investigate further...

Comment: This is a rather delayed side note, but I place it here for the present users. Let $U_{x}$ some unitary operator indexed by $x$, which varies smoothly with respect to $x$ almost everywhere. Now, let $p(x)$ be some probability distribution. The, $\sqrt{p(x)}U_{x}$ Is an uncountable family of Kraus operators and indeed $\int dx\big(\sqrt{p(x)}U^{\dagger}_{x}U_{x}\sqrt{p(x)}\big) = \mathbb{I}\int dxp(x) = \mathbb{I}$.  So you see, if your Kraus operators are scaled unitary operators, then you may have as many as you'd like. The "splitting" mentioned by @EmilioPisanty, hence, need not be trivial.